# Is it possible to scale the eigenvector matrix up by multiplying or adding with a constant?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, spectral-graph-theory

I am using R to generate eigenvector matrix from [laplacian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) that represent a graph dataset. The issue that I have is that the values of eigenvector matrix are very much low, sometimes in the order of $10^{-20}$! My question is: is it possible to scale the eigenvector matrix up by **multiplying** or **adding** with a constant? I think by doing this, it will increase the magnitude of vectors but I am worried that it may destroy the direction of the vectors.

Thank you very much

Comment: Looking at values in the same column: Are there some values which have the order of $10^{-20}$ and the order of $10^1$ in the same column?

Comment: @Roland Yes, my dataset is very large so I get a matrix of size 12000*12000

Comment: How does multiplying selected columns (or the whole matrix) with the same number (say $10^{10}$) help you? Then you'll have some entries in the order of, say $10^{-10}$, but others are in the order of $10^{10}$.

Comment: @Roland I was thinking of taking the largest value in each column, i.e. each vector, and add it to each element in that vector. This process is then iterated for all of them. Do you see this reasonable?

Comment: This will actually destroy the property that the columns are eigenvectors, as the vector $(1,1,\dots,1)$ can only belong to at most one eigenspace (and you are adding a multiple of that vector to every column).

Comment: @Roland Thank you for being patient. I understand that the multiplying matrix by a scalar should be applied to all elements of the matrix. Another scenario I am thinking of here is to find the largest scalar from the matrix (by searching for every vector and finally get the larger one) and use it as the scalar, what do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57712/discussion-between-steven-and-roland).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is, since the space of all eigenvectors corresponding to an specific eigenvalue is a vector space, so if you multiply them by nonzero constant or even add them you  will still get an eigenvector.

Comment: I just noticed that you said I can also **add** a value not only multiplying. Did you mean as `c+M` where `c` in the constant and `M` is the eigenvector matrix?

Comment: @Steven: If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are eigenvectors to *the same* eigenvalue, then $v_1+v_2$ is an eigenvalue to that eigenvalue as well. This translates to specific columns of $M$.

Comment: @Steven I meant adding two eigenvectors associated to one eigenvalue.